# How can I print intermediate results from a pipeline to the screen?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, tee

I'm trying to count the lines from a command and I'd also like to see the lines as they go by.  My initial thought was to use the `tee` command:

```
complicated_command | tee - | wc -l
```

But that simply doubles the line count using GNU `tee` or copies output to a file named `-` on Solaris.

Comment: Ah.  My searches failed to find that question.

Comment: Searching is never perfect, especially with this sort of command.

Comment: Now we have a new set of keywords. ;-)

Comment: I found it because I have the accepted answer on that one.

Comment: google site:stackoverflow.com <yourstuff> and it will find u everything :p

Comment: Now you got two accepted answers for the same problem!

Comment: I think it is better in [unix.stackexchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
complicated_command | tee /dev/tty | wc -l
```

But keep in mind that if you put it in a script and redirect the output, it won't do what you expect.

Comment: Thanks.  I wonder why I didn't know that /dev/tty points to my terminal name.  Glad I asked since that reduces my code a bit.

Comment: Yeah, /dev/tty is an alias for your current tty.  It's very useful like that.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to `tee` to the console directly as opposed to `STDOUT`:

```
tty=`tty`
complicated_command | tee $tty | wc -l
```